# Growing RAID6 (mdadm) including update of stripe-width

Tags: mdadm, raid6

I am running Debian Bullseye (OpenMediaVault 6) with backports kernel 6.0.3-1. I have set up a RAID6 array consisting of 4x 6TB Seagate Ironwolf HDDs (4KiB sectors with 512KiB emulation).

When I have created the file system I made sure to specify the stride-size and sripe-width (as recommended in some guide that I had read). The chunk size of the array is 512KiB. I have used `stride-size = 512KiB (chunk size) / 4KiB (HDD sector size) = 128` and `stripe-width = 128 (stride-size) * 2 (number of useable disks, RAID6 = N-2) = 256`. Therefore the command that I have used to create the file system was `mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 -E stride=128,stripe-width=256 /dev/md0`. Output of `dumpe2fs -h /dev/md0` confirms the 2 parameters.

Now I would like to add an additional disk to the array to increase the total useable size. With an additional disk the stride-size has to remain at 128 but the stripe-width would need to be 384 instead of 256 . I wonder what the appropriate process to grow the array and adjust the stipe-width is.

1. When I grow the array and the array is being rebuild before the stripe-width is adjusted then the data during the rebuild process won't be placed optimally across the disks, right? Changing the stripe-width after the rebuild would not have any effect on the previously written data.
2. Should I adjust the `stripe-width` before I grow the array to ensure the optimal placement of the data across the disks by using `tune2fs -E stripe-width=384`? Afaik changing the stripe-width only affects newly written data anyway.

For growing of the array and resizing of the file system I am probably going to follow the guide on https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing unless someone has a better one. Nonetheless I would like to clarify how I should handly the change to `stripe-width` before taking any further steps in the process.